# can't cout string only char by char

Tags: c++, string

```
for (i = 0; temp[i] != ' '; ++i)
{
    proizvod[i] = temp[i]; std::cout << proizvod[i];
}
std::cout << "Proizvod:" << proizvod;
```

Cout in second line does nothing and in first it works.

EDIT:

```
std::fstream f;   
std::string temp, proizvod, _cijena;
double cijena;
f.open(m_fileName);
while (std::getline(f, temp))
{
    for (i = 0; temp[i] != ' '; ++i)
    {
        proizvod[i] = temp[i]; std::cout << proizvod[i];
    }
    std::cout << "Proizvod:" << proizvod;
```

Comment: Please form an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: And what is the input you use? Does it contain non-ASCII characters? Does it contain a space character?

Comment: this is first line `banana : 9.92`. first cout prints letters `banana`, second does nothing

Comment: Can you even print an array properly using `std::cout<<proizvod;`? I tried it and while it does print the predefined array content, it also spit out lots of junk ascii chars.

Comment: @Javia1492 `operator<<` is overloaded for `std::string`. It is also overloaded for `const char*`, but of course it is assumed that the char array will end up with `\0`.

Answer (score 1):

You create an empty string:

```
std::string proizvod;
```

then try to write to a non-existent element:

```
proizvod[i] = temp[i];
```

giving undefined behaviour. You could increase the size of the string:

```
proizvod.push_back(temp[i]);
```

or do something other than walking through the string:

```
proizvod = temp.substr(0, temp.find(' '));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `proizvod` is a `std::string`, however you end up messing it up since you are adding elements to it in the loop without having pre-allocating memory for it (remeber that the `string` is initially empty). You need to

```
proizvod.push_back(temp[i]);
```

or use the `std::string` concatenation `operator+=` like

```
proizvod += temp[i];
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do

```
for (i = 0; temp[i] != ' '; ++i)
{
   proizvod[i] = temp[i]; 
   std::cout << "Proizvod:" << proizvod[i];
}
```

with the declarations of `temp` and `proizvod` being `char proizvod[]` and `char temp[]`? This should be easier to understand, where the sizes of `proizvod` and `temp` would be your max size.

Comment: You cannot declare a "dynamic" array like that, `char proizvod[]`: `error: storage size of 'proizvod' isn't known`. You need to specify its size, or initialize it from a give string constant. None of these solutions are very appealing, since you don't know in advance how many chars you'll read from the file. That's why a `std::string` is a much better choice.

Comment: @vsoftco I didnt give it a specific size because i did not know the max limit of what OP needs. I assumed he could figure that out for himself. The intent is not to create a dynamic array, but a static array (which its size is unknown to you or me since we do not know the max size of what OP wants to store).

Comment: You should clarify then a bit in your answer. The only issue I see with such an approach is that you have to specify a max. size for the array, and also `std::getline` won't work with it, you'd need to use `istream::getline` instead.

Comment: @vsoftco: Edited my post to hopefully clarify it. Also, i think its a better approach as far as readability because it just seems understandable when you're looking at a `char` array instead of a string being used like an array. Having to use `istream::getline` does not change much.